# Firebase Authentication Error Handling Issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Using Google Firebase Authentication in combination with React to let users register with a name, emailadres and password. I am attempting to run the register function when the form gets submitted, the desired behaviour would be that if it returns a firebase error (invalid email for example) that the error message gets displayed as placeholder within the email field and the user wont get navigated to /login.

At the moment the users keeps getting navigated to /login, which should only be the case if the account was succesfully created.

At the same time I'm having issues saving the username that the user submits, including name as a parameter in the registerWithEmailAndPassword function seems to be causing issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Register.jsx component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import logowhite from '../media/logowhite.png'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'
import {
    auth,
    registerWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithGoogle,
} from '../firebase'


const styles = {
    removed to reduce length
}

const Register = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const handleHome = () => {
      navigate('/')
    }

    const handleLogin = () => {
        navigate('/login')
    }

      
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [passwordCopy, setPasswordCopy] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== passwordCopy) {
        document.getElementById("password2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("password2").placeholder = "Passwords don't match";
        document.getElementById("password2").style.border = "2px solid red ";
        document.getElementById("password2").style.borderRadius = "10px";
        document.getElementById("password2").style.padding = "4px";
        document.getElementById("password2").style.fontSize = "14px";
    } else if (password.length < 6) {

        document.getElementById("password").value = "";
        document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "Password must be longer";
        document.getElementById("password").style.border = "2px solid red ";
        document.getElementById("password").style.borderRadius = "10px";
        document.getElementById("password").style.padding = "4px";
        document.getElementById("password").style.fontSize = "14px";

    } else if (email.length < 6) {
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").placeholder = "Email must be longer";
        document.getElementById("email").style.border = "2px solid red ";
        document.getElementById("email").style.borderRadius = "10px";
        document.getElementById("email").style.padding = "4px";
        document.getElementById("email").style.fontSize = "14px";
    } else if (name.length < 3) {
        document.getElementById("name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("name").placeholder = "Name must be longer";
        document.getElementById("name").style.border = "2px solid red ";
        document.getElementById("name").style.borderRadius = "10px";
        document.getElementById("name").style.padding = "4px";
        document.getElementById("name").style.fontSize = "14px";
    } else {
        registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
         .then(() => {
            navigate("/login")
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
            document.getElementById("email").value = "";
            document.getElementById("email").placeholder = error.message;
            document.getElementById("email").style.border = "2px solid red ";
            document.getElementById("email").style.borderRadius = "10px";
            document.getElementById("email").style.padding = "4px";
            document.getElementById("email").style.fontSize = "14px";

        })

    }
  };
  
  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) return;
    if (user) navigate("/dashboard");
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [user, loading]);


  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.topContainer}>
            <div className={styles.logo}>
                <img src={logowhite} alt="logo" onClick={handleHome} />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.registerButton}>
                <button className={styles.register} onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.loginContainer}>
            <div className={styles.loginTitle}>
                Create Account
            </div>
            <form className={styles.loginForm} onSubmit={register}>
            <div className={styles.loginFormEmail}>
                    <div className={styles.emailTitle}>Name:</div>
                    <input required type="text" id='name' placeholder="John" value={name} className={styles.loginFormEmailInput} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <div className={styles.loginFormEmail}>
                    <div className={styles.emailTitle}>Email:</div>
                    <input required type="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" id='email' value={email} className={styles.loginFormEmailInput} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                </div>

                <div className={styles.loginFormPassword}>
                    <div className={styles.passwordTitle}>Password:</div>
                    <input required type="password" placeholder="********" className={styles.loginFormPasswordInput} value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} id="password" />
                </div>

                <div className={styles.loginFormPassword}>
                    <div required className={styles.passwordTitle}>Confirm Password:</div>
                    <input type="password" id="password2" placeholder="********" className={styles.loginFormPasswordInput} onChange={(e) => setPasswordCopy(e.target.value)}  />
                </div>

                

                <div className={styles.submitContainer}>
                    <button className={styles.submit}>Submit</button>
                    <div className={styles.googleBtn} onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
                        <div className={styles.googleIconWrapper}>
                            <img className={styles.googleIcon} src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg" alt={"google"}/>
                        </div>
                        <p className={styles.btnText}><b>Sign in with google</b></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

My firebase.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  getAuth,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import {
  getFirestore,
  query,
  getDocs,
  collection,
  where,
  addDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
const firebaseConfig = {
 X
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
    const user = res.user;
    const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
    const docs = await getDocs(q);
    if (docs.docs.length === 0) {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        uid: user.uid,
        name: user.displayName,
        authProvider: "google",
        email: user.email,
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert(err.message);
  }
};



const logInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    console.log("logged in");

  } catch (err) {

    console.error(err);
    
    
  }
};




const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
  try {
    const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, name, email, password);
    const user = res.user;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      uid: user.uid,
      name,
      authProvider: "local",
      email,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
const sendPasswordReset = async (email) => {
  try {
    await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
    alert("Password reset link sent!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert(err.message);
  }
};
const logout = () => {
  signOut(auth);
};
export {
  auth,
  db,
  signInWithGoogle,
  logInWithEmailAndPassword,
  registerWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendPasswordReset,
  logout,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `registerWithEmailAndPassword` catches any errors that it gets from Firebase and swallows them:

```
const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
  try {
    const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, name, email, password);
    const user = res.user;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      uid: user.uid,
      name,
      authProvider: "local",
      email,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

If you want your code that calls `registerWithEmailAndPassword` to be able to respond to the error, you should not catch and (pretend to) handle it in `registerWithEmailAndPassword`. SoL

```
const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
  const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, name, email, password);
  const user = res.user;
  await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    uid: user.uid,
    name,
    authProvider: "local",
    email,
  });
};
```